# result set reading value strange behavior

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I've write my method like any other write until now (and all works fine), but this have a problem.
The code execute a select query on a database and create an ArrayList of MyObject type:

```
MyObject current;
ArrayList<MyObject> res = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Connection conn=ConnectionManager.getConnection();
Statement stm = conn.createStatement();         
ArrayList<MyObject> res = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Result set rs = stm.executeQuery(QUERY);

while(rs.next()) {
    current = new MyObject();
    current.setField1(rs.getInt(1));
    current.setField2(rs.getInt(2));
    System.out.println(current.getField1+" "+current.getField2());
    res.add(current);
}
```

(MyObject extends a superclass that contains method setField2(int a) ).
The problem in the sequent. If i execute the query directly on database i have this result:

> 0 5000
>
> 1 5000
>
> 2 6000

but the execution of query on Java code returns

> 0 6000
>
> 1 6000
>
> 2 6000

MyObject and MySuperObject class

```
public class MyObject extends MySuperObject {
    potected int field1;
    public MyObject() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public int getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }
    public void setField1(int f) {
        this.field1 = f;
    }
}


public class MySuperObject {
    potected int field1, field2;
    public MySuperObject() {
    }

    public int getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }
    public void setField1(int f) {
        this.field1 = f;
    }

    public void setField2(int f) {
        this.field2 = f;
    }

    public int getField2() {
       return this.field2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're pointing to the same database configuration.

Comment: I would add log (or) sys out before setFiled2(..); just to make sure it is not query issue.

Comment: i'm sure that's not query issue. I've modify my code with a println (i've edited my message), and i obtain the correct value.

Comment: You could debug, or simply print rs.getInt(1) and rs.getInt(2)... something like int int1 = rs.getInt(1); System.out.println(int1);

Comment: does that System.out.println(current.getField1+" "+current.getField2()); print the correct results ?

Comment: yes. But i have the wrong result when i call this method inside my code

Comment: First, make sure the results of the query are the same from both your SQL console tool and your Java execution (in Java side, use log or sysout to verify the result of `rs.getInt(1)` and `rs.getInt(2)`). After verifying this, follow the behavior of the code when being consumed from your `MyObject` instance, probably there's an additional rule you haven't considered.

Comment: the result are the same. The error it's probably while create the object. I've edit post with MyObject and MySuperObject class

Comment: MySuperObject has a constructor named MyObject.

Comment: potected <-- how did it compile?

Comment: I found the following line twice in the code, so it cannot be compiled:  ArrayList<MyObject> res = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

Comment: sorry, it's only a cut & paste error